# compare multidimensional array to find array with largest value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that has name and integer values in them. I need to be able to compare the integer value in each array in the multidimensional array. how can I compare and return that array?

```
var totals = [
    ['john', 'test', 45],
    ['bob', 'tester', 75]
];
```

How can I loop over the arrays in the "totals" array and return the one with the largest integer value?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). For example:

```
var totals = [
    ['john', 'test', 45],
    ['john', 'test', 46],
    ['john', 'test', 42],
    ['john', 'test', 41]
];

var biggest = totals.reduce((a, b) => a[2] > b[2] ? a : b);
console.log(biggest);
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/19gc4y0o/)

---

It should be noted, that if `reduce()` is not supplied with an initial value, then `a` becomes the first, and `b` becomes the second in the first call.

Answer (score 0):

```
var largest = totals.reduce((prev, cur) => prev[2] > cur[2] ? prev : cur, [0,0,0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = totals.reduce((p, c) => {
    return p[2] > c[2] ? p : c;
});

console.log(result);
```